Ibis Collapse Transitive Matches
I have an Ibis table where I’m trying to collapse transitive matches between pairs that match. For example, if I have a table that looks like



group
A_match
B_match
C_match
D_match
E_match




1
1
1





1


1
1



1




1



I want it to still look like that after collapsing. But let’s say I have a table that looks like



group
A_match
B_match
C_match
D_match
E_match




1
1
1





1


1
1



1

1
1




1




1



Then I want it to look like this after collapsed



group
A_match
B_match
C_match
D_match
E_match




1
1
1
1
1



1




1



How can I do this purely in Ibis? I don’t want to convert anything to Pandas. Is there a way to use aggregation or something?
